# How to check if function is running for the first time?

Tags: java, android

So I am currently modifying a code.
In the piece of code I am attaching below, mShakeImage.start() is executed every time the activity is first launched.
I want to eliminate this and stop mShakeImage.start() from triggering the first time the activity is launched. How do I achieve this?

**CODE**

```
@Override
public void displayEvent(@AccelerationEvent int event, int data) {
    if(mCurrentDetectEvent == FeatureAcceleratonEvent.DetectableEvent.FREE_FALL)
    {
        mShakeImage.start();
        Context context = getContext();

        //-----------test for position of shake image---------------------
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle("Alert")
                .setMessage("This is an alert")
                .show();

        //---------------call function from CallScreen()------------------
        Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), CallScreen.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: U can create a SharedPreferences with default value 0 and then after first run change value to 1, if(preference == 0 ) mShakeImage.start()

Comment: could you help me put it in code. I am really new to android studio coding and I dont know how to use SharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("firstTime", true)){
            mShakeImage.start();
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("firstTime", false).apply();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to put a check on this function, like whether it is executed before are not and for that you need to save a value in sharedpreferences.

Suppose we save a value in sharedpreferences inside that method and check it before the call to that method like

```
if(!sharedPreferences.getBoolean("firstTime", false))
            mShakeImage.start();
```

now if we check it for first time you install app in device. this condition will be false and your function will be executed.

Now inside `mShakeImage` function we save/change true value inside sharedPreferences so on second time the condition will not met and `mShakeImage` will not be called.